# Deep directives design in Angular

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I know isolated scope and read some resources about Angular. Now I am stuck with a problem; suppose I have very deep directives:

```
A wraps B wraps C wraps D wraps E
X wraps Y wraps D wraps E
```

A, B, C, D, E, X, Y are directives. D and E need some information of something which are passed to their isolated scopes, I call this info is `info: '='`. This `info` belongs to A or X. So if I need to use `info` in D and E, I have to pass it in paths: `A -> B -> C -> D -> E` or `X -> Y -> D -> E`.

That means B, C, or Y have to create their isolated scopes to hold `info` value. Too deep! If I in future add some directives in the middle of paths, I have to do same thing as above. I don't think it's good design.

Can anyone give me some suggestions on to resolve this design problem in Angular?

Comment: Maybe you should use a service to share information between the directives?

Comment: @Bema: yeah, I know I can use service but I'm looking for the clean way to do that. Because suppose I have 10 elements `A -> B -> C -> D -> E` how I can tell to D directive of 8th element to take `info` of A directive of same element? It's harder way, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. You could:

1 - Keep info inside a service and just inject it wherever you need.

2 - Allow directives to communicate with each other via controller. So for example, if you want directive E to get information form directive A, A must have a controller and some kind of getter method, directive E would require this controller and use the get method inside the link function. Easier to visualize with code.

```
.directive('aDir', function () {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     transclude: true,
     template: '<p>aDir: {{info}}<span ng-transclude></span></p>',
     scope: {
       info: '='
     },
     controller: function ($scope) {
        this.getInfo = function () {
           return $scope.info;
        };
     },
     link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {

     }
  };
})

.directive('eDir', function () {
  return {
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<p>eDir: {{info}}</p>',
     require: '^aDir',
     scope: { },
     link: function (scope, elm, attrs, aDirController) {
          scope.$watch(function () {
            return aDirController.getInfo();
          }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
              scope.info = newVal;
          });
     }
  };
});
```

[Here is a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qurawanosufa/1/edit).

[Here you have more info about directive's require attribute.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)

Comment: Bingo! That's exactly what I need. I make a mistake is don't read the guide of Angular official site, terrible mistake. But I'm curious there are better/cleaner ways? And `require` property of directive can impact to performance?

Comment: If there is another way I have to say I am not aware, also wouldn't worry about any performance impact, Angular creates only one controller for each directive, so even if you have several aDirs in the page, there will be only one controller for them (It is a nice way to make them talk to each other too). I understand your frustration with the docs, it is a huge amount of information to digest, little by little ;).

Comment: Yes, I think I have to dig the docs. I usually read examples, tuts through google search :) now I have to change my mind. Thanks for your support!

Comment: I forgot one point: `eDir` can get `info` from both `aDir` and `xDir`. How can I apply above code to resolve this point?

Comment: Docs @William ;). First paragraph about the require attribute: "The require takes a string name (or array of strings) of the directive(s) to pass in. If an array is used, the injected argument will be an array in corresponding order."
So instead of ***require: '^aDir'***, you could use ***require: ['^aDir', '^xDir']***

Answer (score 1):

How about using a service to hold the data. Services are singleton objects in Angular. So if you set the value in one place, it'll be visible in another.

So, inject the service into A, set the value there. Inject the service also into D (or wherever it is needed) and read the value there.

You'll probably have to set a watch to react to the change in the place(s) you are reading it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if I do that, I got an other problem: suppose I have 10 elements `A -> B -> C -> D -> E` how I can tell to D directive of 8th element to take `info` of A directive of same element?

Comment: The other way to communicate between directives is by giving them controllers. You can then get a reference to the controller in another directive in the same hierarchy. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: Oh that's great! I miss this tutorial. Sorry if I don't understand this technique correctly, but in my problem, I should create controller for which directives?

Comment: Add a controller to A, and consume it in D.